# Location of postgres db file for backup

Tags: postgresql, backup

I would like to make a backup of a postgres database file that I created on Ubuntu 16.04.

I cannot find the file. Some other sources indicate it should be under:

```
/var/lib/postgresql/[version]/data
```

When I run show data_directory inside of postgres it shows:

```
/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main
```

However there is no data folder there.

Comment: Depends on how you installed postgres. Check `pg_lscluster` if you used the Ubuntu packages, and it'll show you where. But anyway, don't just copy the datadir for backups, use `pg_basebackup` or `pg_dump` and `pg_dumpall`. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup.html

Comment: @CraigRinger I think this should be an actual answer.

Answer (score 2):

To find out where the PostgreSQL data folder is located, just run SQL query:

```
show data_directory;
```

You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8237512/9210727)

**However, note**

File System Level Backup are faster but large in size. The worst thing is that to perform a database's backup, PostgreSQL Server required to be stopped. More information about the restrictions of this operation can be found in the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/backup-file.html). On my own I will add that from such backups, as a rule, there is more harm than good.

The main method for creating backups in PostgreSQL is the [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/backup-dump.html) utility.

```
pg_dump dbname > dbname.dump
```

Opposite file-level backup, a backup via the pg_dump tool does not require stopping the server, it is easy to [automate](https://sqlbak.com/blog/how-to-automate-postgresql-database-backups-in-linux) and does not require access to the server file system (it can be performed [remotely](https://ksearch.wordpress.com/2012/09/28/how-to-backup-a-remote-postgresql-db-and-restore-it-locally/)).